# pygame draw.rect() and draw.line() functions seem to override each other

Tags: python, pygame

I need to draw grid with rows*cols fields(nodes in my case) and for this I used `pygame.draw.rect()` and this runs ok, but when I wanted to draw grid lines with `pygame.draw.line()` I came across some "weird" behavior. Namely, the `end_pos` of horizontal lines seems to depend on the current value of `i` in the `for loop` when `pygame.draw.rect()` is present in the `redraw()`.

```
import pygame as pg 

pg.init()

clock = pg.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

WIN_DIM = 800
window = pg.display.set_mode((WIN_DIM, WIN_DIM))


class Grid:

    grid = []

    def __init__(self, row, col, win_width):
        self.rows = row
        self.cols = col
        self.win_width = win_width
        self.node_width = win_width // row

    def make_grid(self):
        for row in range(self.rows):
            Grid.grid.append([])
            for col in range(self.cols):
                Grid.grid[row].append("node")


def redraw(grid):

    window.fill(pg.Color("White"))
    for i, row in enumerate(grid.grid):
        for j, node in enumerate(row):
            pg.draw.rect(window, pg.Color("White"), (0 + i*grid.node_width, 0 + j*grid.node_width, grid.node_width, grid.node_width))
            pg.draw.line(window, pg.Color("Grey"), (j * grid.node_width, 0), (j * grid.node_width, grid.win_width))
        pg.draw.line(window, pg.Color("Grey"), (0, i * grid.node_width), (grid.win_width, i * grid.node_width))
    pg.display.update()


def main_loop():

    main_grid = Grid(10, 10, WIN_DIM)
    main_grid.make_grid()

    run = True
    while run:

        clock.tick(FPS)

        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                run = False

        redraw(main_grid)


main_loop()

pg.quit()
```

[image: grid_with_rect]

But when I remove `pg.draw.rect()` in `redraw()` then everything is fine:

[image: grid_without_rect]

I suspect that outlining of the `rect` somehow "overrides" the `line` but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suspect that outlining of the `rect` somehow "overrides" the line but I am not sure.

Yes of course. You draw 1 white rectangle followed by 1 gray line in a nested loop. You don't draw all the white rectangles before the gray, lines are draw. The rectangles and lines are drawn alternately:

> ```py
> for i, row in enumerate(grid.grid):
>    for j, node in enumerate(row):
>        pg.draw.rect(window, pg.Color("White"), (0 + i*grid.node_width, 0 + j*grid.node_width, grid.node_width, grid.node_width))
>        pg.draw.line(window, pg.Color("Grey"), (j * grid.node_width, 0), (j * grid.node_width, grid.win_width))
>   pg.draw.line(window, pg.Color("Grey"), (0, i * grid.node_width), (grid.win_width, i * grid.node_width))
> ```

Compare it to:

```py
for i, row in enumerate(grid.grid):
    for j, node in enumerate(row):
        pg.draw.rect(window, pg.Color("White"), (0 + i*grid.node_width, 0 + j*grid.node_width, grid.node_width, grid.node_width))
for i, row in enumerate(grid.grid):
    for j, node in enumerate(row):
        pg.draw.line(window, pg.Color("Grey"), (j * grid.node_width, 0), (j * grid.node_width, grid.win_width))
    pg.draw.line(window, pg.Color("Grey"), (0, i * grid.node_width), (grid.win_width, i * grid.node_width))
```

Comment: Yes, that was the issue, now works as expected. Thank you